# Jetpack Paging 3 inside java/kotlin module

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, clean-architecture, android-paging

I'm developing an app with clean architecture principles. I've a `domain` module which is a `Java/Kotlin` module and it hasn't android dependencies and a `domainImpl` module which is an `Android` module and has dependencies to `local`, `remote` and `domain` module. this is a `Repository` example inside `domain` module:

```
interface MovieRepository {
    fun getMovie(id: Long): Flow<Movie>
}
```

and below code is it's implementation inside `domainImpl` module:

```
class MovieRepositoryImpl(
    private val movieApi: MovieApi
) : MovieRepository {

    override fun getMovie(id: Long): Flow<Movie> = flow {
        emit(movieApi.getMovie(id))
    }

}
```

Everything works fine in this case. But Now I'm trying to add `Android Paging 3` for my pagination. So I have to add a method to the `MovieRepository` interface like:

```
fun getMovies(): Flow<PagingData<Movie>>
```

But before this I've to add Paging library to my `domain` module but unfortunately it is an `Android` library and I couldn't find a core dependency for it. So What can I do about it? Do I have to change my `domain` module to an android module because of this? Or is there any other workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548387/android-paging-library-with-clean-architecture

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The non android components of Paging are in `androidx.paging:paging-common` - any dependencies on presenter APIs are Android specific by definition so any code related to `RecyclerView`, `LazyColumn`, etc will need to be Android specific.

However `PagingSource`, `PagingData`, `Pager`, `RemoteMediator` are all provided by `paging-common`, so your implementation of those classes, including your transformation chain and overall output of `Flow<PagingData>` can be completely android-free.

Comment: Does this dependency work for you? I tried to add it to my pure Kotlin domain module but I receive "Cannot resolve dependency" error. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does your gradle file look like? AndroidX artifacts are hosted on Google's maven server here: https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=paging#androidx.paging:paging-common

Comment: @TomaszKopacz please make sure you should have to use Java Version 1.8 instead of 1.7

Comment: thanks man, I resolved my problem by updating the java version to 1.8 on the gradle