# Clean Architecture with paging3 and compose passing PagingData to domain layer

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, clean-architecture, android-paging-3

I am using clean architecture with paging 3 and trying to populate a lazyColumn.

I have the following class in my data layer module and I don't want to pass the PagingData to the domain layer as I want to keep the domain free of any Android SDK.

```
class RepositoryImp @Inject constructor(
    private val foodService: FoodService,
    private val foodDatabase: FoodDatabase) : Repository {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    override fun fetchAllComplexSearch(): Flow<ResponseState<List<ComplexSearchEntity>>> {
        val pagingSourceFactory = { foodDatabase.foodDao().fetchAllComplexSearchPaging() }

        val pagingDataResult = Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE_DEFAULT),
            remoteMediator = ComplexSearchRemoteMediator(
                foodDatabase = foodDatabase, foodService = foodService
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
        ).flow


        val data = pagingDataResult.map { pagingData ->
            pagingData.map { complexSearchModel ->
                ResponseState.Success(
                    listOf(
                        ComplexSearchEntity(
                            complexSearchModel.id,
                            complexSearchModel.title,
                            complexSearchModel.image,
                            complexSearchModel.imageType
                        )
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        
        return data
    }
```

I want to return this `Flow<ResponseState<List<ComplexSearchEntity>>>` But I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Flow<ResponseState<List<ComplexSearchEntity>>>
Found:
Flow<PagingData<ResponseState.Success<List<ComplexSearchEntity>>>>
```

It seems like I am wrapping the ResponseState.Success(...) inside the `PagingData`

Then the presentation layer module will map the Response.Success in a PagingData to be used as a `LazyPagingItems<ComplexSearchEntity>` in a LazyColumn.

Comment: Maybe you could  initialize your Pager in the viewmodel?

Comment: I don't want to move setting up the Pager in the viewModel. Because the mediator is in the data layer and the presentation layer should not know about the data layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired functionality, your repository should expose a `PagingData<ComplexSearchEntity>` rather than a `ResponseState<List<ComplexSearchEntity>>`. This adjustment allows for a cleaner architecture by keeping paging logic within the repository layer and not spreading data layer objects to other layers, thus maintaining a clear separation of concerns.

For your domain model to support this, you can include the following dependency, which is pure Kotlin compatible and allows a repository or use case to expose `PagingData`:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.paging:paging-common:3.2.1")
```

Then, within your repository implementation, you should move the logic for creating the `Pager` from the UI or ViewModel layer to the repository itself. Here's how you could implement this:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
override fun fetchAllComplexSearch(): Flow<PagingData<ComplexSearchEntity>> {
    val pagingSourceFactory = { foodDatabase.foodDao().fetchAllComplexSearchPaging() }

    return Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE_DEFAULT),
        remoteMediator = ComplexSearchRemoteMediator(
            foodDatabase = foodDatabase, foodService = foodService
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
    ).flow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66271127/13083841) you can use common artifact of paging library in your domain module.